# After building QT from source, theme color is white

Tags: qt

I successfully built QT from source on a virtual machine. I then compiled a small app. It built just fine, except that when I moved the executable to the host machine. It background color is white, not dark like the theme. This problem does not happen when I build the app on the host. So my question is, is there a flag, or a file I can change it make the background color dark?

Comment: check your Ressources if you where referencing a qss file (Qt Style Sheet) Otherweise if you where defining the colors in your app, it should be there.

Comment: Does your app use OpenGL? If the answer is yes: as long as you tried the app on the host machine and the background not appearing that implies the build itself.

The behavior you describe is most likely implies that OpenGL is not working. The cause is likeliest that Qt build itself. Try to rebuild Qt with -opengl es2 for both enabling OpenGL and ANGLE compatibility. But completely wipe build directories (I erase entire src and start over anew) or else it will probably fail (it did fail rebuilding for me). You can also -opengl desktop but that option may fail on certain systems.